# Why am I not able to filter properly with drop_while?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

With respect to the following code:

```
static constexpr auto v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int n : v | std::views::drop_while([](int i) { return i < 3; }))
   std::cout << n;
std::cout << n << ' ';
```

I am getting the expected output:

```
3 4 5
```

However, when I change the less than (<) to greater than(>) inside the Lambda function, why am I getting the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

What's the functionality of the OR operator (|) in this case?

Comment: When reversing the order of the elements, it should go better, see: https://onlinegdb.com/5fDFWMZLQQ   (But I have not enough knowledge into C++ to explain )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_while_view)'s description for `drop_while`:

> A range adaptor that represents `view` of elements from an underlying
> sequence, beginning at the first element for which the predicate
> returns `false`.

When you change the condition of the lambda, since the first element does not satisfy the predicate, no elements are filtered.

What you want is [`views::filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view), which will filter out *all* elements that don't satisfy the predicate.

Comment: Thanks. Your final paragraph indicates that the answer is in my query itself ('filter')!